# Getting data from Digital Database for Screening Mammography (DDSM)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get the DDSM dataset in a readable format.

Does anyone have a working version of DDSM’s heathusf program that works on linux or windows with normalization? I know there is a working version of DDSM's jpeg program for linux at http://www.cs.unibo.it/~roffilli/sw.html
I compiled and tested it. I used the MATLAB code as described here to view the images.
It displays correctly only for some scanners.

As described in the paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.111.3846 when properly compiled, the DDSM software outputs the image data as a stream of raw bytes; one then has to normalise these according to the model of digitiser used to image the original films and then create an image file that is readable by one’s image analysis software environment.
Does anyone have a solution for normalizing the image data?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Cheng

Comment: I used to work with this dataset a long time ago. I don't remember any special issues with normalization. Can't find my code, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a **complete** solution that downloads, normalizes (based on the scanner) and converts the DDSM image to PNG format.  Dr. Chris Rose wrote that program, and it is available on GitHub at https://github.com/multinormal/ddsm

Answer (score 6):

DDSM images are compressed in .LJPEG format and they need to be decompressed first before processing them.

I've figured out a way to convert DDSM images into raw images, but it is a long way, and I don't have a better way.

- **Reading DDSM dataset images in steps:**

  1. Clone the repository at https://github.com/multinormal/ddsm, which contain two executables [ `jpeg.exe` and `ddsmraw2pnm.exe` ].

2- Download and install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe).

3- Download and setup  [Matlab pnmreader code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4176-pnm-toolbox-3-01?download=true).

4- Create a folder and make its contents like the following:

- jpeg.exe
- ddsmraw2pnm.exe
- ConvertDDSMImageToRaw.m [ *implementation comes later in answer* ]
- cygwin1.dll  [ *from "C:\cygwin" or anwhere else where you've installed cygwin* ]

5- the `ConvertDDSMImageToRaw` function implementation.

```
function ConvertDDSMImageToRaw(filename, columns, rows, digitizer)
%// ConvertDDSMImageToRaw Convert an image of ddsm database to raw image.
%// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
%// Input:-
%//  o filename : String representing ddsm image file name.
%//  o columns  : Double representing number of columns in the image.
%//  o rows     : Double representing number of rows in the image.
%//  o digitizer: String representing image normalization function name,
%//     which differ from one case to another and have the set of 
%//    values ['dba', 'howtek-mgh', 'howtek-ismd' and 'lumisys' ]
%// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
%// Prepare and execute command of image decompression
commandDecompression = [which('jpeg.exe') ' -d -s ' filename];
dos(commandDecompression);
%// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
%// Prepare and execute command that convert the decompressed image to pnm format.
rawFileName          = [ filename '.1'];
columns              = num2str(columns);
rows                 = num2str(rows);
digitizer            = ['"' digitizer '"'];
commandConversion    =[ which('pnm.exe') ,' ',rawFileName,' ',columns,' ',rows,' ',digitizer];
dos(commandConversion);
%// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
%// Wrtie the image into raw format
pnmFileName          = [rawFileName '-ddsmraw2pnm.pnm'];
image                = pnmread(pnmFileName);
imwrite(image,[filename '.raw']);
end
```

6- get the image information `[cols,rows,digitizer]` from the .ics file:

[image: .ics file example]

if the digitizer is 'howtek' use it as 'howtek-mgh', that's what I've figured out.

7- convert you image now using the function we've impelemented, like the following:

```
filename  = 'A_1709_1.LEFT_CC.LJPEG';
digitizer = 'howtek-mgh';       
imageSize = [ 5341  2806 ];
ConvertDDSMImageToRaw(filename, imageSize(1) , imageSize(2), digitizer);
```

Comment: LJPEG ... another "interesting" exotic image file format. Is there a sample file anywhere publicly available for testing this procedure?

Comment: @ernestopheles .. you can download some images from [http://marathon.csee.usf.edu/Mammography/Database.html]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/trane293/DDSMUtility) is yet a better source.

As mentioned in the tutorial this is less labor intensive.

And I have used it. It works perfectly and easily. Just remember to use 32-bit version of cygwin only. It did not work with 64 bit cygwin for me.