# Converting image from .LJPEG to .png using MATLAB from DDSM database for breast cancer but MATLAB doesnt produce any output

Tags: image, matlab, cygwin, png, winscp

I am doing a research on image processing using mammography image from **Digital Database of Screening Mammography (DDSM) database.**

I found the way to convert the image in `.LJPEG` format into `.png` that can be read by MATLAB from here https://github.com/trane293/DDSMUtility.
I had followed the tutorial but the result is not as expected.

I should have the `.LJPEG` converted to `.png` after run the script in MATLAB but unfortunately nothing happened.

Is there anyone who using the same database and successfully converted the images?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the output of `identify your_file.LJPEG` ? Identify is part of ImageMagick package

Comment: cygwin terminal. Assuming you have installed the ImageMagick package

Comment: Type this: $ `identify C_0001_1.LEFT_CC.LJPEG` and got this:
**identify: Unsupported JPEG process: SOF type 0xc3 `C_0001_1.LEFT_CC.LJPEG' @ err          or/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/322.**

Comment: can you also check the output of `gm identify your_file.LJPEG` . gm is in the GraphicsMagick package. Additional, can you share one of this image for test ?

Comment: `-bash: gm: command not found`. the image is from here. http://marathon.csee.usf.edu/Mammography/DDSM/thumbnails/cancers/cancer_01/case0001/C-0001-1.html. sorry, I dont know how to upload image here.

Comment: dear @shai, I am currently using both tutorial in the link that you provided and that is how this question came up. because the result is not as expected from the solution. please do not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @rafidahmuhamad please explicitly refer to the linked question in your post and explain why it does not work for you.

Comment: referring to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365587/getting-data-from-digital-database-for-screening-mammography-ddsm?noredirect=1&lq=1, the best answer was from here https://github.com/multinormal/ddsm and after following the tutorial, I have a problem at verifying whether `ruby` was installed correctly by typing `ruby -e "p 'Hello world!'"`. there is nothing printed out if I typed it and if I used ` ` instead of **' '**, it said that **-bash: !`: event not found**

Comment: So you have a problem with Ruby ! All your question was misleading

Comment: oh, i didnt know that. thank you. ill post a new question.